# Looking for name of R function for subsetting observation

Tags: r, row, subset

I'm unsure of what to Google.

I have a column, lets call it `x`. Within this variable, each row is a list of strings. For example

`1: A,B,C,D,E`

`2: A,B,C,D,E`

I am wondering the name of the R function to select, process, etc. within each row? E.g. I may wish to extract only B from each row. Or perhaps delete all C's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that it is a `data.table`, we extract the character 'B' with `str_extract`

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
dt[, x:= str_extract(x, "B")]
```

and if we want to delete all 'C's, it can be done with `gsub` from `base R` or `str_replace_all` from `stringr`

```
dt[, x := gsub(",*C", "", x)]
```

#### data

```
dt <- data.table(x = c('A,B,C,D,E', 'A,C,D', 'B,C,C,D'))
```